Is "offer a" the same as "offer to a"?
In regard to the following two questions:
"What do you have to offer a woman?"
and
"What do you have to offer to a woman?"
Are they both correct? If so, is one preferred over the other?

The short answer is that they are both correct but could carry slightly different meanings. The former "What do you have to offer a woman?" is probably the preferred in the context. To explain why is a little more complicated.
The preposition "to" is often needed to indicate the direction of the relationship, and in other contexts "to offer [x]" can mean that the object [x] is the being being offered, for example "I offered a job (to him)". In your example, the preposition "to" is not necessary because the verb "offer" can function directly with its object (the thing being offered) and an indirect object (the recipient) without needing a preposition. This arguably creates some ambiguity, but you'd have to read heavily into it and nobody is likely to think that 'a woman' is the thing being offered.
The option without "to" is preferred is also somewhat idiomatic. What a person can offer, in a relationship or a job etc, encompasses all of the qualities they bring. It is more of a general, open statement. Asking what they can offer "to" a woman sounds more like a singular thing.
